# Visual Studio 2010 Chart control: Make Y Axis an Integer value, not decimal

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, charts

I like the way that the chart control seems to automatically determine the X axis range for me based on the data, but in this case, the data can only be whole numbers.

What is the easiest way to specify whole numbers for this axis?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    chartClicks.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you can do this by setting the `YValueType` property on any relevant series to an integer type - for example:

```
Chart.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't working for very small amounts (1-5 clicks). I have solved that like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> clicks = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    clicks.Add(string.Format("{0:00}:00", i), 0);
}

foreach (DateTime dateTime in rawClicks)
{
    clicks[string.Format("{0:00}:00", dateTime.Hour)]++;
}

Chart chart = new Chart();    
chart.ChartAreas.Add("Default");

Axis x = chart.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX;
Axis y = chart.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY;

x.Interval = 1;
x.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;

chart.Series.Add("Default");
chart.Series["Default"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "15";

int maxNumberOfClicks = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    string key = string.Format("{0:00}:00", i);
    chart.Series["Default"].Points.AddXY(key, clicks[key]);

    if (maxNumberOfClicks < clicks[key])
    {
        maxNumberOfClicks = clicks[key];
    }
}

y.Interval = Math.Ceiling((double)maxNumberOfClicks / (double)7);
if (y.Interval == 0)
{
    y.Interval = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="Default">
        <AxisY Interval="1" IntervalType="Number"></AxisY>
    </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
```

Comment: What is the y axis range was great, say 1 to 200? The y axis ticks should only be on a whole number but the increment should probably be more than 1. Since this post is very old, this is something that I can't easily try.